# Generics. Create 2 objects and add them to another object

Tags: java, generics

I am hoping that someone can guide me in the right direction with this. I have to create 2 Dog Objects and then add them to MyPets Object as myFirstPet and mySecondPet. I have multiple classes such as Animal, Dog, Greyhound which implements the Comparable interface and MyPets(The generic class).

MyPets Class:

```
public class MyPets<T> {

    private T myFirstPet;
    private T mySecondPet;

    public void setMyFirstPet(T myFirstPet) {
        this.myFirstPet = myFirstPet;
    }

    public void setMySecondPet(T mySecondPet) {
        this.mySecondPet = mySecondPet;
    }

    public T getMyFirstPet(){
        return myFirstPet;
    }

    public T getMySecondPet(){
        return mySecondPet;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "My first pet " + myFirstPet + ", my second pet "
                + mySecondPet;
    }
}
```

TestClass class which has the main:

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyPets<Dog> dog = new MyPets();
        MyPets<Dog> doggie = new MyPets();

    }
}
```

I am unsure as to what I need to do here to add the 2 dog objects to MyPets objects as myFirstPet and mySecondPet. I also don't even know if I have created the Dog objects properly.

Comment: Did you give it a try? HINT: Make use of setter methods.

Comment: I'm not sure that a dog is a new MyPets(). It rather be a new Dog(), no ? ^^

Comment: It compiles this way but obviously isn't going to do anything. I am unsure as to what else I need to do. I have tried dog.setMyFirstPet("Fluffy"); but ends up with this error
" The method setMyFirstPet(Dog) in the type MyPets<Dog> is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

Comment: When changing MyPets() to Dog() then its not creating an instance of MyPets with parameter type of Dog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Careful...you haven't actually created any `Dog` objects; you instead created two `MyPets` objects. But since each `MyPets` is *itself* really just a list of other `Animal` objects, it doesn't make sense to treat an instance of `MyPets` as a `Dog`.

Your code should actually look something like:

```
Dog dog = new Dog(/* use your constructor for Dog here... */);
Dog doggie = new Dog(/* use your constructor for Dog here... */);
MyPets<Dog> dogList = new MyPets<Dog>();
//Since this appears to be homework I'll let you figure out what to do here...
```

Comment: Great, hope it helped. Please upvote any answers people gave that you found useful, and accept (click the checkmark) next to the answer you feel best answers your question.

Comment: Yes it did help. I will upvote when I get the reputation. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Your test must be like this:

```
    public class TestClass {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            MyPets<Dog> pets = new MyPets();
            Dog first = new Dog();
            Dog second = new Dog();
            pets.setMyFirstPet(first);
            pets.setMySecondPet(second);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're getting lost in the generics syntax. You need to separate out (*conceptually*) the distinction between a `MyPets<Dog>` object vs. a `Dog` object.

Your task is to create two `Dog` objects, and then add them to a single `MyPets<Dog>` object. The code you've written above creates two `MyPets` objects, but no `Dog` objects. Further, it doesn't use any of the functions you wrote (`setMyFirstPet` and so on)--frequently a sign in assignments like this that your logic is missing a step.

What your `main` method should look like (in the abstract, to avoid doing your work for you) is something like this:

- Create a `MyPets<Dog>` object.
- Create two `Dog` objects.
- Add both `Dog` objects to the `MyPets` object (using the `setMy[First/Second]Pet` methods).

Comment: Thank you. I don't really understand more or less the syntax as to what is wanted in the description of the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The class that you wrote stores pairs of the same object(Lets not discuss inheritance here).Assuming that you have two classes `Cat` and `Dog` and you want to store references to objects of these types using you class, you do this:

```
MyPets<Dog> myDogs = new MyPets<Dog>();
myDogs.setMyFirstPet(new Dog("Roger"));/*Assuming this is your dog constructor*/
myDogs.setMySecondPet(new Dog("Rocket"));
System.out.println(myDogs);
MyPets<Cat> myCats = new MyPets<Cat>();
myCats.setMyFirstPet(new Cat(/*A cat name*/));
myCats.setMySecondPet(new Cat(/*Another cat name*/));
```

There are many subtleties to generics. One thing you should keep in mind is that at run time, there is no T. The T in your MyPets class is converted to reference of type Object. T is only used at compile time to ensure that the objects you pass to MyPets are indeed of type T. In the code above, if you pass a Cat object to the MyPets where T = Dog, it will be a compile time error, not runtime.